# C# monotorrent client embed problem

Tags: c#, bittorrent, monotorrent, bitsharp

I need to embed torrent client (ability to download files by .torrent file) inside of my C# application. I am using monotorrent library to do that.
I need to write windows app that can download files to my local folder by .torrent file.

I have downloaded assembly for C# project from here http://www.monotorrent.com/projects/list_files/monotorrent

Here is code i am using :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MonoTorrent.Client;
using MonoTorrent.Client.Encryption;
using System.IO;
using MonoTorrent.Common;
using System.Net;


namespace monotorrent
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ClientEngine engine;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Torrent torrent = Torrent.Load("C:\\1.torrent");

        // Create the manager which will download the torrent to savePath
        // using the default settings.
        TorrentManager manager = new TorrentManager(torrent, "E:\\torrent", new TorrentSettings());

        // Register the manager with the engine
        this.engine.Register(manager);

        // Begin the download. It is not necessary to call HashCheck on the manager
        // before starting the download. If a hash check has not been performed, the
        // manager will enter the Hashing state and perform a hash check before it
        // begins downloading.

        // If the torrent is fully downloaded already, calling 'Start' will place
        // the manager in the Seeding state.
        manager.Start();
    }
}
}
```

When i run the code and press download button i have got an error :

Cannot load type "MonoTorrent.Common.Torrent" from assembly   "monotorrent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

I think this is a problem with assembly . But where can i get a normal assembly(.dll) ?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

P.S. if you know more simple solution to embed torrent client to windows form app - You are wellcome =)

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling the library yourself (by opening VS and doing a build) rather than using some lib (*.dll) you've found somewhere off the net. Also, are all the dependencies there?

Comment: Here is the sources http://www.monotorrent.com/attachments/download/28/monotorrent-0.80.tar.gz   Can you help me to compile it to dll? How can i do that? i cannot find any .sln or csproj file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place reference to monotorrent.dll in your project. You can get it [here](https://nodeload.github.com/mono/monotorrent/zip/master) or compile from sources from [here](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent)